# Find and replace with sed/regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am running this `sed` command in a bash file:

```bash
sed -i -E 's/(={|=")([^}]+)(}"|})/\2/g' "$filename"
```

But, I'm getting this error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 27: Invalid content of \{\}`

The regex should match `="{123}"` or `={text}` (with or without quotes) and replace it with the second capture group (content of `{}`). I have checked the regex on https://regex101.com/ and it does what I expect. Help, what am I (not) doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: `{` and `}` have special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape them.

Comment: and escape all `|`.

Comment: @Cyrus: As far I can see, only the `{` needs to be escaped. The `|` is supposed here to have its special meaning in an extended regexp, and the `}` does not have an effect, if the opening brace is escaped: See for instance `echo x{}x|sed 's/[{]}/v/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
sed -E 's/=("?)\{([^}]+)\}\1/\2/g' "$filename"
```

Here regex to match: `=("?)\{([^}]+)\}\1`
It uses back-reference `\1` to avoid quotes disbalance (like `={qwe}"`).

Otherwise, it's mostly yours regex.

Demo of usage at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7q07U2/1)

Comment: Can confirm this works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sample input:

```
$ cat file
a="abcd"
n="{123}"
o={text}
z="xyz"
```

A couple ideas:

```
$ sed -E 's/=["]{,1}\{([^}]+)}["]{,1}/=\1/g' file
a="abcd"
n=123
o=text
z="xyz"


$ sed -E 's/=.*\{([^}]+)}.*/=\1/g' file
a="abcd"
n=123
o=text
z="xyz"
```

Once the output is validated OP can add `-i` to have `sed` perform an 'in place' update of the file.

Comment: Thanks! The first one works. And thanks for reminding me about `=`.
The second one does not match as expected, though.

Comment: hmmmm, both generate the same output for me; what version of `sed` (`sed --version`) are you using? I'm running `GNU sed 4.9`

Comment: I'm running `GNU sed 4.8`. And `sed is already the newest version (4.8-1ubuntu2)`.